# Training a SVM on Facial keypoints - how do I cast the features to the correct shape?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to train a SVM (in python, scikit-learn) to recognize facial expressions.  I've gotten the facial keypoints from a bunch of images, and put them into a list of lists, but this data format isn't correct for a SVM.

Each of my "training points" is an array of shape (68, 2) corresponding to the coordinates of 68 facial keypoints associated with that image. So my x_train ends up being a 3D array, whereas a SVM requires an array of dimension <= 2.

What's the best approach to restructure this data? I could cast the (68,2) into (136,), but would that preserve my features?  I feel like that would lose the features that I'd like the SVM to be able to classify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to reshape your training points into one dimension.

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 136)
```

My understanding of SVMs is that they should be able to cope with this as there is no loss of information, but someone else will have to justify this mathematically.